# Bluetooth hci0 is not detected corretcly

Tags: bluetooth

I know that MEDIATEK MT7922 should be able to handle bluetooth, yet I can not turn it on. I tried everything from reinstalling bluez, btusb, etc...

Just now I dicovered that the system seems to think my bluetooth is Foxconn of USB type, even though MT7922 is PCIe.

```
kepler-22b@Horizon-A082:/etc/modprobe.d$ lsusb
Bus 009 Device 002: ID 145f:01e5 Trust Keyboard [GXT 830]
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1ea7:0064 SHARKOON Technologies GmbH 2.4GHz Wireless rechargeable vertical mouse [More&Better]
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e0e0 Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0408:5477 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP Wide Vision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As you can see there are no results:

```
kepler-22b@Horizon-A082:~$ sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
kepler-22b@Horizon-A082:~$ 

kepler-22b@Horizon-A082:~$ sudo dmesg
[10897.716096] pcieport 0000:00:01.1: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:01:00.0
[10897.716147] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[10897.716152] nvidia 0000:01:00.0:   device [10de:25a2] error status/mask=00000040/0000a000
[10897.716159] nvidia 0000:01:00.0:    [ 6] BadTLP                
[10897.747266] pcieport 0000:00:01.1: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:01:00.0
[10897.747317] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[10897.747326] nvidia 0000:01:00.0:   device [10de:25a2] error status/mask=00000040/0000a000
[10897.747331] nvidia 0000:01:00.0:    [ 6] BadTLP               
...
```

I restarted the computer and tried again:

```
    kepler-22b@Horizon-A082:~$ sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[sudo] password for kepler-22b: 
[    0.096311] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.278550] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.731282] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.731303] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    2.731304] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.731306] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.731308] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.731312] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.997148] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: WM Firmware Version: ____000000, Build Time: 20220523103447
[    3.978585] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x0400002A
[    3.981232] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.23 DEC: 2 VEP: 0 Revision: 5
[    3.981237] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    4.402662] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.402666] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.402670] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.898529] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
```

[image: sudo inxi -Fxz]
[image: System]
[image: hciconfig]
[image]

Comment: It is indeed ubuntu 22.10, I upgraded the kernel because I thought it could fix my bluetooth issue. To upgrade the kernel, I used Ubuntu mainline kernel installer, so far except from a randomly crashing google chrome, everything works fine. My inbuilt microphone is also not working.

Comment: Please edit to add results from terminal for `lsusb`  Please copy and paste text from terminal rather than posting screenshots

Comment: And results for `sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: The 5.19 Ubuntu kernel likely needs https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?h=v6.1&id=7ac7267fad5908476b357e7e9813d23516c2b0a1

Comment: My kernel is upgraded to 6.0 ... Besides, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with the link you've given me.

Comment: Should I downgrade my kernel to 5.19?

Comment: It doesn't look like proper support is in 5.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by kernel upgrade.

My system now runs on 22.04 LTS since 22.10 complicated things for the Nvidia drivers and rather than fixing issues, it added more.

Xanmod stable kernel
https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-xanmod-kernel-on-ubuntu-linux/

> I do not posses the knowledge to understand what every instruction of the link above does, but it solves the problem until a newer distro fixes those issues. I would appreciate it if someone explained or pointed out whether there's an issue in the instructions.